# List of files opened by process

Tags: python, windows, filesystems

How would I go about getting the list of files currently opened by a single application (.exe).

For example, I've running the media player [MPV](https://mpv.io/) and it's playing a video file, knowing its PID how can I get the files being held by the process?

Running this code

```
p = psutil.Process(15228)  # manually set PID of MPV for testing
pprint.pprint(p.open_files())
```

It returns the following array

```
[popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\System32\\pt-BR\\msvfw32.dll.mui', fd=-1),
 popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf', fd=-1),
 popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\System32\\pt-BR\\kernel32.dll.mui', fd=-1),
 popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\System32\\pt-BR\\MMDevAPI.dll.mui', fd=-1),
 popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\System32\\pt-BR\\avicap32.dll.mui', fd=-1)]
```

I can successfully obtain the current playing file if I get the *cmdline* by using `p.cmdline()` and removing the folders leading up to the file, but that can only be used if the video file was opened directly, if the player has been opened first then the file dragged to it, there's no *cmdline* to be parsed.

For the time being it can be platform dependent solution for Windows.

Comment: This is a brittle approach: 1) The process will have *many* non music files open. 2) What if it has more than one music file open? I would expect a good music player to cache a song in memory before it starts playing it.

Comment: You're asking yourself the wrong question. The right question is, "How do I know which song is playing in my media player?" You could write a "user script" to save that information to a special file that you choose. Take a look at the autoload plugin on [this page](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/wiki/User-Scripts) for how to grab the current song.

Comment: @jpaugh Its video files, I'm parsing the file so I can get the Name;Year;Extension and store that to a local database. Is there another way to monitor Windows to get what files are being opened? Then I can compare if its a valid video file then proceed the program.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't care whether the song is currently playing or not? Then why not scan your music folder instead?

Comment: @jpaugh. It's not songs, I'm trying to make a TV-series/movies tracker of sorts. It will track which series and what episode is playing, so I don't have to do it manually.

Comment: Okay. My second comment is probably the easiest way. And, it would be cross platform. Work with the technology you have, rather than against it.

Comment: @jpaugh I used MPV only as a example. I plan to get which file is playing on more than just mpv. VLC and MPC-HC too for example.